# run coffeescript if user is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to find a way to only run a specific piece of coffeescript code if the user is signed in. Is there a way to achieve this without having to include that specific coffeescript file. For example check if a session cookie with the value of `user_id` is found, then run this piece of code.

The goal is to remove some inline javascript and move them over to the assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails by default uses `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore` so theoretically you could read the cookie and get the user id. However to avoid spoofing and session based attacks the cookie is encrypted. And you can't decrypt it without exposing the Rails `secret_key_base` to the client - which is a really bad idea or forgoing the protection of encrypted cookies.

Instead might just want to let your view / layout tell you if there is a signed in user:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chess</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<%= content_tag(:body, data: { "signed-in" => user_signed_in?.to_s }) do %>
  <%= yield %>
<% end %>
</html>
```

This will let you read `$('body').data('signed_in')` and avoids exposing / duplicating any of the actual authentication logic on the client. This also works well with Turbolinks since Turbolinks replaces the `body` tag.

You would use it like so:

```
// @return Boolean
function is_user_signed_in(){
  $('body').data('signed-in') === 'true';
}
```

Comment: I was unable to get this working, but I see my difference is I have `'data-turbolinks-track' => true` while it seems you don't on your javascript include tag. Ideally I'll keep turbolinks?

Comment: I'm not sure if matters in this case - I think later versions of turbolinks track all assets unless you explicitly set it to false. Turbolinks is definatly nice if you spend some time learning how it works and the gotchas.

Comment: I just realized this does not quite work as intended since `hash.compact` only removes keys where the value is nil - not false. So in this case it may just be simpler to output a string and compare to "true".

Answer (score 0):

You can move your javascript out to assets.
Expanding on max's answer, it can then look at the value of $('body').data('signed_in')
for example:

```
if($('body').data('signed_in') == true){
  //execute
}
```

So your javascript still needs to be included in the client's browser but using some logic like that above allows you to only run if there is a user signed in.

Comment: I'm unable to get my code run with this, if I run ($('body').data('signed-in') at the console it returns true, but the code is never ran. When I remove it, the code runs however.

Comment: I typed the variable name incorrectly, it should be this, does this work?  if($('body').data('signed-in') == true){
  //execute
}

Comment: obviously I was aware of the mistake, but it still doesn't work

Comment: You have marked Max's answer as the best. If you are still having problems, try not using turbolinks. I have had problems using turbolinks in the past so turning it off temporarily might be a useful debugging strategy. In the console does $('body').data('signed-in') == true return true?